# BufferOverflowException when using instances of BufferedImage's to create video - Xuggler

Tags: java, video, xuggler

I have a ***LinkedList< BufferedImage > imgList*** object. When I add BufferedImage I can create video. When I use

```
BufferedImage tmp1 = img.getSubimage(0,0,500,500);
imgList.add(temp1);
```

**img** is BufferedImage with a loaded image.

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:363)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:859)
at com.xuggle.xuggler.video.BgrConverter.toPicture(BgrConverter.java:132)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.convertToPicture(MediaWriter.java:970)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeVideo(MediaWriter.java:805)
at xuggler.CreateVideo.<init>(CreateVideo.java:61)
at xuggler.CreateGraphics.<init>(CreateGraphics.java:108)
at xuggler.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Here is the class in which I create the video:

```
public class CreateVideo {

private static final double framerate = 30;
private static final String outputFilename = "outputvideo.mp4";

public CreateVideo(LinkedList<BufferedImage> imgList) {

  final IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(outputFilename);


   writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MPEG4,  bordwidth/2, bordheight/2);

   long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        for (BufferedImage imgs : imgList){

        writer.encodeVideo(0, imgs, System.nanoTime() - startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

        try {
               Thread.sleep((long) ((1000)/ framerate));
            } 

        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

      }//End for

       writer.close();

 }//end CreateVideo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the size of imgList and writer. It looks your writer object can not handle all images in imageList object? Check if this helps

Comment: I reduced the size of imageList object. There was nothing different. I don't understand how to check the size of writer object.